# what will the equivalent statement of line in main?

Tags: c++

```
class B{
    float floatVar;
    public:
    B(float a):floatVar(0.0){
        floatVar = a;
    }

    operator int(){   // Consider this as line A
        return floatVar;
    }
};


int main()
{
    B floatObj(5.5);    
    cout << floatObj;  // Consider this as line B

    return 0;
}
```

when i cout while overloading int() it displays 5 and when i replace int() with float() in line A , program displays 5.5.
I want to know how it is automatically calling the int() typecaster or the float() in cout?

Comment: In overload resolution `std::ostream::operator<<` is found and it has overloads taking `float`, `int` etc. so implicit conversion is attempted from `floatObj` to each of those overloads. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt

Comment: @M.M I added one more data member and now it is not working? What's happening?

Comment: hang on, let me find my crystal ball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler is allowed to perform one user-defined conversion implicitly when searching for matching function overload. Since you provide conversion from `B` to `int`, compiler can use that and select `operator <<(std::ostream, int)` overload of the `<<` operator for `std::cout`.

---

If you would add another conversion to a type that is accepted by `operator <<` for `std::ostream` (e.g. `float`), compiler would say that it is ambiguous call and it cannot choose by itself.

```
class B{
    float floatVar;
    public:
    B(float a):floatVar(0.0){
        floatVar = a;
    }

    operator int(){
        return floatVar;
    }
    operator float(){   
        return floatVar;
    }
};


int main()
{
    B floatObj(5.5);    
    cout << floatObj;  //error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'B')

    cout << static_cast<int>(floatObj); //explicit conversion, compiles
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no synthesis of default *printing* function or alike in C++, thus defining a class with some fields doesn't print them by default if you try to print an objet of the class.

As you didn't defined any overloaded operator `<<` to print to some `ostream` (like `cout`) the compiler found a way to print it through the defined conversion to `int`.